# how to display a protected html page within an iframe

Tags: php, html, iframe

I have a bunch of resources outside the root of my webserver. This resources are mainly html files with related css and js. I'm trying to use them within my current page and it looks like I should use an iframe for that.

The problem is that I load the html within such iframe but it is displayed without any style. I checked with firebug and the css is included properly but the properties defined there are not aplied.

Can you help me? thanks in advance :)

**Updated whit some more info**

I have a list of resources inside a folder that is outside apache's public folder

/usr/resources/resource1.html

this html file uses relative routes to css and js that is inside the same non-accesible folder:
/usr/resources/css/style.css

I serve this html file through a php script (using readfile). I have a list of resources inside a menu, when a user clicks on a resource name I change the iframe src attribute with jQuery to refresh it, as I said, I see the html loaded (with all the css loaded as well) but styles are not applied. I'm a little bit stucked here :S

**Solution**
I found a solution, the problem was that headers for js and html files weren't properly returned by finfo_file (it returned text/plain for both) so they weren't applied to the iframe.

Comment: The styles should be applied. Can you give us more information on how you're implimenting this etc?

Comment: No, the styles should not be applied. The HTML page loads because PHP loads it. The CSS is not in the web root, how is it supposed to get to the browser if the web server won't serve it up? In other words you visit myserver.com/myfile.php, which loads some other html file on your server, fine. If it tries to link in a CSS file, it's got to be accessible to the php script, obviously, because that's what's being served up.

Comment: @GGG that's what I thought but what I don't understand is why the html loads the css, I mean, If I explore the html with firebug I see the css rules but they are not applied...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added this here in case it can helps someone:

The problem was that headers for js and html files weren't properly returned by finfo_file (it returned text/plain for both) so they weren't applied to the iframe. When I fixed this everything worked as expected.

Regards